# How hide the grub 2 start up screen in debian during bootup?

Tags: debian, grub2

How can I make it so that the grub start up screen will not show up in debian when I boot?

[image]

Comment: @Creek nope, that's with GRUB 1, this is with GRUB 2. Completely different configuration.

Comment: @derobert That question is actually about Grub 2 — not sure why some people posted a Grub 1 answer but the asker was running Grub 2 and the accepted answer describes both.

Comment: @Gilles My apologies, with it being an old question, one of the answers only covering grub1, and the other only covering grub2 as an afterthought, I figured it was just grub1. I missed OP's comment. That said, the answer still isn't really over there, as it doesn't say which variable in `/etc/default/grub` to edit. I guess if we want just one hide grub startup screen question, we should merge the two questions (well, or rather get a mod to merge them for us).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Change timeout settings in `/etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
   ```
2. Update Grub

   ```
   update-grub
   ```